# How do I declare constant strings in C and what use are they?

Tags: c, string, static, constants

How can I declare constant strings and what use are they in programming? I don't know If I'm doing this right but would this be the correct way of doing it?:

```
    const char my_string="Hello";
```

Comment: If you compile that line of code, you'll see that it's not correct.

Comment: So true, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php

Comment: This would be explained in the first few chapters of any [decent introductory C book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Are you sure you actually want a *constant string* or are you actually wanting a *string literal*?

Answer (score 1):

```
const char my_string="Hello";
```

This is not valid C. A string literal like `"hello"` is of type `char[n]`, not `const char`. The correct declaration is

```
const char my_string[] = "Hello";
```

Also, its a good idea to name your constants in ALLCAPS.

Comment: A C string literal is of type `char[]` -- not `const`, and not a pointer. (Like any expression of array type, it's implicitly converted to a pointer in most but not all contexts.)

Comment: @KeithThompson fixed

Comment: The convention of using all caps usually applies to macros. `my_string` is a declared object, not a macro, and not strictly speaking a constant.

Answer (score 0):

here's the answer:

- Method 1

  `const char my_string[] = "Hello";`
- Method 2

  `const char *my_string="Hello";`

as you ask why it is used in C Programming the answer is when we want the value to remain the same and to protect the value from being overwritten we declare the variable as constant.

Comment: And yet, here, `*my_string` is a non-constant variable that points to constant data, so that variable is *not* protected from (over)writing.

Answer (score -3):

In the ***C*** programming language, the meaning of `const` is *much* less powerful than it is in other, more-recent, languages. In fact, <strike>it could well be said that</strike> the meaning is not the same at all.

To quote http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/const-qualifier-in-c/ ... *(emphasis and omissions mine):*

> The ***qualifier*** `const` can be applied to the declaration of any
>   variable to specify that its value will not be changed [...] *The
>   outcome is implementation-defined(!)* if an attempt is made to change
>   a const.

The key thing to notice here is that, in ***C*** *(which, in its defense, dates from the 1970's),* the keyword `const` is a *qualifier.*  It **is *not*** a "compile-time constant!"

The C language used `#define` declarations as its closest approximation to the behavior that other languages use when presented with the keyword, `const`.

Consider the following web-page, *"The C++ 'const' declaration, Why & How,"* where author Andrew Hardwick frankly discusses the treatment of this keyword in both the C and the C++ languages:  http://duramecho.com/ComputerInformation/WhyHowCppConst.html

Contrast *both* of these languages to other languages' treatment of this word, which they consider to be a **declaration** *(not a qualifier)*, and which they universally treat in an *entirely* different way.

Comment: You discuss the meaning of `const`, but you don't actually answer the question. And there's a simpler explanation of what `const` means: it means *read-only*.

Comment: It seems abundantly clear to me ... and of course, I could be utterly mistaken ... that the OP "has *[almost every ...] other languages' meaning" of the word `const` in mind. Hence, my (long-winded) post. "While you are absolutely correct, Keith, *in the context of 'C' as well-understood by those of us who use it regularly,"* I see in front of us a source-string "that would be entirely at home" in almost every *other* language." That's the point-of-view that guided my response.

Comment: The OP asks how to declare "constant strings", and shows an example that would be correct with the addition of a `*`. The question isn't 100% clear, but I'm pretty sure you haven't actually answered it.

Comment: ***You and I(!)*** know what would be *"correct with the addition of a `*`!" But, does the *OP* know that? My guess(!) was that, "just maybe, he *doesn't."* (Maybe he's relatively new to C/C++, in which case: "the rules *here* are altogether different.) It was, in the end, a "just trying to be helpful" *guess.*

Comment: Bottom line: You didn't answer the question.

Comment: I yield to your opinion without further comment, and openly **encourage you** to down-vote *(if you have not done so already)* at your pleasure.